# Debug assertion error on printing

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, rich-text-editor

I have a simple text editor that I created in Visual Studio 2010 Professional Edition. Basically I modified the MFC MDI program automatically generated by the VS2010 wizard. The problem is that when i print, it gives me a debug assertion error in viewrich.cpp line 294. I have not modified anything in the code to do with printing, though it could be something wrong with how i used Rich Edit. This is all the information I have. Thanks in advance.

Viewrich.cpp

```
BOOL CRichEditView::PaginateTo(CDC* pDC, CPrintInfo* pInfo)
// attempts pagination to pInfo->m_nCurPage, TRUE == success
{
ASSERT_VALID(this);
ASSERT_VALID(pDC);

CRect rectSave = pInfo->m_rectDraw;
UINT nPageSave = pInfo->m_nCurPage;
ASSERT(nPageSave > 1); // LINE 294
ASSERT(nPageSave >= (UINT)m_aPageStart.GetSize());
VERIFY(pDC->SaveDC() != 0);
pDC->IntersectClipRect(0, 0, 0, 0);
pInfo->m_nCurPage = (int)m_aPageStart.GetSize();
while (pInfo->m_nCurPage < nPageSave)
{
    ASSERT(pInfo->m_nCurPage == (UINT)m_aPageStart.GetSize());
    OnPrepareDC(pDC, pInfo);
    ASSERT(pInfo->m_bContinuePrinting);
    pInfo->m_rectDraw.SetRect(0, 0,
        pDC->GetDeviceCaps(HORZRES), pDC->GetDeviceCaps(VERTRES));
    pDC->DPtoLP(&pInfo->m_rectDraw);
    OnPrint(pDC, pInfo);
    if (pInfo->m_nCurPage == (UINT)m_aPageStart.GetSize())
        break;
    ++pInfo->m_nCurPage;
}
BOOL bResult = pInfo->m_nCurPage == nPageSave;
pDC->RestoreDC(-1);
pInfo->m_nCurPage = nPageSave;
pInfo->m_rectDraw = rectSave;
ASSERT_VALID(this);
return bResult;
}
```

EmergenceView.cpp

```
IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE(CEmergenceView, CRichEditView)

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CEmergenceView, CRichEditView)
// Standard printing commands
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT, &CRichEditView::OnFilePrint)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_DIRECT, &CRichEditView::OnFilePrint)
ON_COMMAND(ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW, &CEmergenceView::OnFilePrintPreview)
ON_WM_CONTEXTMENU()
ON_WM_RBUTTONUP()
ON_COMMAND(ID_MUTATE_GROUP, &CEmergenceView::OnMutateGroup)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_MUTATE_GROUP, &CEmergenceView::OnUpdateMutateGroup)
ON_COMMAND(ID_MUTATE_RANDOMISE, &CEmergenceView::OnMutateRandomise)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_MUTATE_RANDOMISE, &CEmergenceView::OnUpdateMutateRandomise)
ON_COMMAND(ID_HELP_STATISTICS, &CEmergenceView::OnHelpStatistics)
ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_HELP_STATISTICS, &CEmergenceView::OnUpdateHelpStatistics)
ON_COMMAND(ID_MUTATE_POETRIZE, &CEmergenceView::OnMutatePoetrize)
ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_SELECTALL, &CEmergenceView::OnEditSelectall)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// CEmergenceView construction/destruction

CEmergenceView::CEmergenceView()
{
// TODO: add construction code here

}

CEmergenceView::~CEmergenceView()
{
}

BOOL CEmergenceView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
// TODO: Modify the Window class or styles here by modifying
//  the CREATESTRUCT cs

return CRichEditView::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}

// CEmergenceView drawing

void CEmergenceView::OnDraw(CDC* /*pDC*/)
{
CEmergenceDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
if (!pDoc)
    return;

// TODO: add draw code for native data here
}


// CEmergenceView printing


void CEmergenceView::OnFilePrintPreview()
{
    #ifndef SHARED_HANDLERS
AFXPrintPreview(this);
    #endif
}

BOOL CEmergenceView::OnPreparePrinting(CPrintInfo* pInfo)
{
// default preparation
return DoPreparePrinting(pInfo);
}

void CEmergenceView::OnBeginPrinting(CDC* /*pDC*/, CPrintInfo* /*pInfo*/)
{
// TODO: add extra initialization before printing
}

void CEmergenceView::OnEndPrinting(CDC* /*pDC*/, CPrintInfo* /*pInfo*/)
{
// TODO: add cleanup after printing
}
```

Comment: Could you post the MFC code that asserts, together with your code that  initiates the printing

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `OnPreparePrinting` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a59dff1e.aspx), it appears that you have to call `pInfo->SetMaxPage()`.

Answer (score 0):

The ASSERT says it all:

```
UINT nPageSave = pInfo->m_nCurPage;
ASSERT(nPageSave > 1);
```

This is a value for the current page to print/paginate. It is set to 1 in CPrintInfo's constructor. But something changed it and made it 0 or negative. Usually this value is completely controlled by the RTF printout. So you must done something that manipulates it.

You have to set the Minimum page and the Maximum page value (SetMinPage and SetMaxPage) in CPrintInfo.

Comment: I have set both min page and max page and it is still giving me the same error...